# Is it possible to execute currently opened script from within `mcedit`?

Tags: midnight-commander

When I change small scripts in `mcedit`, I sometimes want to "test" them immediately. Switching to another terminal/virtual console is quite annoying, so ther must be a better way.
Actually, not every script is marked as executable, altough in most cases they at least have shebang line.

Is it possible to execute currently opened script from within `mcedit`?
If so, can I pass parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your User menu file to add/modify key bindings. See [here](http://wiki.frugalware.org/index.php/MCedit#User_menu_commands).

As I didn't have a `~/.mc/cedit/menu` file, I copied it from `/etc/mc/cedit.menu`

If you want to run scripts marked as executable and pass parameters you'd add something like

```
r       run
        PARAM=%{parametes}
        %f $PARAM
```

to your `~/.mc/cedit/menu` file.

In this example *r* will be the key for running scripts once you are in the User menu (F11), change *r* to whatever you like. `%f` is a macro for the open file's filename.

For shell scripts not marked as executables you'd have change the last line in the example above to read

`sh %f $PARAM`

There are hints for syntax and lots of templates in the menu file.
Also there are filters for filenames extensions, see those templates to have some examples.

Comment: menu entry appears. Instead of the saved script, it seems to run a copy in `/tmp`. Unfortunately the output isn't provided: no logmessages, no interactivity with the user...

Comment: A simple script with pwd in it shows the right path (ie. not /tmp). I didn't have problems with interactivity. To see the output try Ctrl+o, or see the c/c++ language template in your menu file (echo -ne "...Press any key to..."; read). Remember to pass at least one parameter if you asked for them (as in my example above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that from within mcedit, but if you run mcedit as the internal editor of midnight commander you hit Ctrl+o to go back and forth to the command line with no need for another terminal.

Comment: that's what I did for quite a while - its annoying. I could use `screen` as well, but that's not what I want.